# Buildship Java launch configuration missing JARs when specific version of Glassfish JAXB referenced

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-11, buildship

## Background

I'm migrating a large project to OpenJDK 11.0.2 from 8. As such I need to include JAXB implementation.

## Problem

I've observed that applications launched from within Eclipse 
2019-03 (4.11.0) using Buildship (3.0.1.v20181217-1554) don't contain any external JAR dependencies.

This only effects launch configurations, compilation is fine.

## Analysis

I've isolated the fault to when version 2.4.0-b180725.0644 of the Glassfish JAXB implementation is used. Using 2.3.1 works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this issue

Note. Now raise https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548455

## Test case

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    runtime group: "org.glassfish.jaxb", name: "jaxb-runtime", version: "2.4.0-b180725.0644"
    // runtime group: "org.glassfish.jaxb", name: "jaxb-runtime", version: "2.3.1"
}
```

Java test file

```
public class LaunchConfigurationIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String each : System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator)) {
            System.out.println(each);
        }
    }
}
```

Output when 2.3.1 used

```
C:\adam\git\foo\bin\main
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\5af35056b4d257e4b64b9e8069c0746e8b08629f\log4j-1.2.17.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.xml.bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\a09d2c48d3285f206fafbffe0e50619284e92126\txw2-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\c197c86ceec7318b1284bffb49b54226ca774003\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jvnet.staxex\stax-ex\1.8\8cc35f73da321c29973191f2cf143d29d26a1df7\stax-ex-1.8.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.xml.fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\bb7b7ec0379982b97c62cd17465cb6d9155f68e8\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
C:\Users\adam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
```

Output when 2.4.0-b180725.0644 used

```
C:\adam\git\foo\bin\main
```

Comment: I guess that the hint may be here: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#a-2-4-0: "JAXB RI is now JPMS modularized, All modules have native module descriptor. Removed jaxb-core module, which caused split package issue on JPMS. RI binary bundle now has single jar per dependency instead of shaded fat jars." I have not used the new Java 9 modules in production yet, but what I remember from experiments, this is exactly the type of issues they cause :)